# Java Sound Api: Wav file not playing after saving recording on disk

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am making a sound recording from the mic and saving it as a .wav file to disk.

I can't play the wav file with Media Player ? Is this normal ?

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); // format is an AudioFormat object

    // Obtain and open the line.
    try {
        targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        targetLine.open(format);
        targetLine.start();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int numBytesRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

        targetLine.start();

        while (recording) {
           numBytesRead =  targetLine.read(data, 0, data.length);
           out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        }     


        File fileOut = new File("C:\\audio\\audio6.wav");
        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(targetLine);

        if (AudioSystem. isFileTypeSupported(AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,ais)) {
            AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, fileOut);
            System.out.println("writen");
        }   
        targetLine.stop();

        ais.close();
```

Comment: It should work. Is there any data in the file or is it just junk

Comment: You're not using the contents of your ByteArrayOutputStream - why not?

Comment: @Jon I was trying an alternative write: //      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut); 
//     
//    out.writeTo(outputStream);
//    outputStream.close();
//    out.close();

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to play the file in media player if it's working correctly.

I would recommend getting a copy of the free audio editor Audacity (http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and looking at the data. 
Firstly check that there is some data in the file and then check that you have the endian, bit depth and sample rate correct (Switch around and see if any of them make a sensible noise).

If that doesn't work try reading in some samples from a file rather than the Mic and then checking they are the same when they come our the other end.

If you haven't found it already this is a great resource for Java Audio
http://www.jsresources.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the recorded data into the ByteArrayOutputStream out, and then never doing anything with it (as pointed out by Jon Skeet).

When the "recording" boolean is false, THEN you attach the TargetDataLine to the AudioInputStream? But if recording is false, then I assume there is no data coming through the TDL. Data is obtained from a TDL via the read() method, and it is within the while loop.

I think it is possible to make an AIS via the ByteArrayInputStream which can be made from the ByteArrayOutputStream that you used to collect the data from the TDL.

Thus, after the recording boolean goes false, try making your AIS this way:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, baos.size());
```